# How do I darken one container in a GestureDetector when I have multiple buttons created with a Widget constructor in Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, button, gesturedetector

So I have a piece of code where I need to add multiple buttons to the same page. I am using a GestureDetector since I don't like the onPress animation for the actual buttons.

I wish to darken the color when it's touched. The way it happens doesn't really matter, as long as I don't have to add different variables for every button I add.
My current code is using a single variable for each of the buttons, which, needless to say, changes all the buttons when the variable is updated.

```
GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      // Funtion to change color of PageButton child
                      setState(() {
                        colorTapped = !colorTapped;
                      });
                    },
                    child: PageButton(
                      text: 'BUTTON 1',
                      color: colorTapped,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      // Funtion to change color of PageButton child
                      setState(() {
                        colorTapped = !colorTapped;
                      });
                    },
                    child: PageButton(
                      text: 'BUTTON 2',
                      color: colorTapped,
                    ),
                  ),
```

PageButton widget:

```
class PageButton extends StatelessWidget {
  PageButton(
      {required this.text, this.width, this.height, required this.color});

  final String text;
  bool color;
  // final IconData icon;
  final double? width;
  final double? height;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        color: color ? Color(0x66DE4B4D) : Color(0xFFEF4B4D),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: kLargeButtonTextStyle,
        ),
      ),
      width: width ?? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
      height: height ?? 50.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0),
    );
  }
}
```

Long story short: I want to change the color of the child Widget onTap without having to create a variable each time I add a button

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the approach described by flutter documentation to animate the properties of a container: you have to modify the instance properties based on the GestureDetector `onTap` property.
This means:

1. you have to make it a stateful widget, in order to allow it to change
2. use its instance variables to change separately every single button's property

Here's the link: [Flutter Documentation: Animate the properties of a container](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/animated-container)